# PrimeFaces V.8.0: Datepicker-Popup don't close when closing Dialog with Enter-Key

Tags: primefaces, datepicker

When im on the Input field of Datepicker and I'm pressing the Enter-Key, the dialog windows is closing. Data is beeing saved. The problem is that the Pop-up of the datepicker is still open. I have to click the Pop-up "away". When clicking the submit or abort button in the dialog the Pop-Up disappears. I'm using version 8.

Uncaught TypeError: PF(...).close is not a function

`<p:datePicker`  
... 
  `widgetVar="dateValue123"`  
  `hideOnDateTimeSelect="true"`  
  `onkeydown="if (event.keyCode === 13) {PF('dateValue123').hide()} />`

Instead of `.hide()`, I also tried `.close()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.show()` and `.hide()` were added later on the widget but you can MonkeyPatch your 8.0 code with this JS code and your code above will start working.  I also believe your original issue you are trying to solve is also fixed in a later version of PrimeFaces.

```js
if (PrimeFaces.widget.DatePicker) {

    PrimeFaces.widget.DatePicker.prototype.show = function() {
        this.jq.data().primeDatePicker.showOverlay();
    };


    PrimeFaces.widget.DatePicker.prototype.hide = function() {
        this.jq.data().primeDatePicker.hideOverlay();
    };
};
```

Comment: As information for the readers: The hide() function does work know but my code don't solve my issue.